# Setting tintColor disables desaturation when window is not active

Tags: objective-c, swift, mac-catalyst

When I set tintColor a UIButton it will stop desaturating when window resigns being active.

How can I restore this behaviour?

In first row is button with default tint.
In second row with systemGreenColor as tintColor.
[image: Effect]

The behaviour is the same when I change tintColor of superview from which UIButtons inherit tintColor.
OS: macOS Big Sur or Catalina
Framework: Mac Catalyst

Nick

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one tint color for your whole app, try adding that color to your asset catalog and then set that as the “Global Accent Color Name” flag in your build settings.

Tutorial:
https://www.bigmountainstudio.com/members/posts/27630-how-do-i-add-a-global-accent-color-to-a-swiftui-1-0-project

That will set the default tint for the whole app.